# Does a program/tool exists where you can control if the recycle bin appears filled?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

I throw a lot of Shortcuts in the recycle bin and I don't want it to appear filled just because some shortcuts which occupy virtually no space on my hard disk. So, is there a program or tool where you can specify a custom amount of storage which the content of the recycle bin must occupy before it appears as filled? For example, if I would set 5MB and the shortcuts in the bin would add to 20KB, it would appear empty.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the specific size thresholds, I haven't seen that. You can always right click on your desktop, go to personalize, change desktop icons (in upper left), then change the full recycling bin to look like an empty recycling bin. But then your bin would always look empty.

There is a checkbox for allowing themes to change desktop icons. It seems like there may be a way for someone to write a windows theme that does what you're asking for as long as the API returns an int for the recycling bin status and not a bool

Comment: I'm not against an filled recycling bin because it looks ugly but because I always think I must look at the files and decide if I delete or keep them because they use hard disk space. So an "always-empty" bin would not solve my problem. The latter solution however seems interesting.